# Class 'Users' not found when running artisan migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I am trying to run

```
project$ php artisan migrate:refresh
```

but get the error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Users' not found
```

Why do I need a `Users` class? I already have `app/User.php`:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

[...]
```

and my migration, `database/migration/2015_05_27_143124_create_users_table`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            [...]
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    [...]
```

My `config/auth.php` also has `'model' => 'App\User'`. I tried running `project$ composer dump-autoload`. The `User` class is being defined. Why do I need a `Users` class?

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, there is no reason that error would be thrown. You may have a reference to `Users` somewhere else. Was there any more to the migration error?

Comment: @StuartWagner no, the only error was this one. Do you think I should search for `Users` in all my files (or a subset of them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I dropped my database and went ahead and made a new one with the same name, then:

```
project$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
```

Comment: Weird. Glad you figured it out, anyway.